# Can I overload operators for specific versions of a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic `Quantity<T>` class for managing physical quantities, looks like this:

```
public class Quantity<T> where T : Unit
{
    public Quantity(double value, T unit)
    {
        this.OriginalUnit = unit;
        this.Value = unit.ConvertBack(value);
    }
...
}
```

The `Unit` class manages the different units a quantity can be in, but it isn't really relevant for my question.

What I would like to do is define operators in the generic `Quantity<T>` class like this:

```
    public static Quantity<ElectricResistanceUnit> operator /
        (Quantity<ElectricVoltageUnit> q1, Quantity<ElectricCurrentUnit> q2)
    {
        return new Quantity<ElectricResistanceUnit>(q1.Value / q2.Value, ElectricResistanceUnit.Ohm);
    }
```

But this does not compile ("one of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type"). Is there any way around this?

One way this works, that is not really a solution for me, is the following:

```
public class ElectricVoltage : Quantity<ElectricVoltageUnit>
{
    public static ElectricResistance operator /(ElectricVoltage q1, ElectricCurrent q2)
    {
        return new ElectricResistance(q1.Value / q2.Value, ElectricResistanceUnit.Ohm);
    }
}

public class ElectricCurrent : Quantity<ElectricCurrentUnit>
{
}

public class ElectricResistance : Quantity<ElectricResistanceUnit>
{
}
```

The problem with this is: I would have to define an empty derived class for all my `Unit`s (which is a LOT), plus this makes me inflexible in composed classed (can't cast `Quantity<ElektricResistanceUnit>` to `ElectricResistance`).

Does someone know a more elegant way of solving this?

Comment: I've created this exact sort of thing before and the way I did it is by representing arbitrary dimensions as rational powers of 5 basis dimensions: length, mass, time, temperature, and electric current.  So rather than having a different class for every possible combination, there's just one class that represents the dimensions of a quantity.  You still don't get compile-time safety, but I can't think of a way to enforce that anyway without hard-coding every combination of dimensions.

Comment: + The facts you have: a unit instance to pass for the operation, + 3 different unit type for the operation (at least if both of them were the same, it would be easier to find a workaround), but like it is now, it seems to be really hard to code it, in a generic way.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! I came to the conclusion that this is probably not possible with generics. So instead of using generics I now use a T4 template to auto-generate hard-coded quantities for all available units. That way I can have compile-time type safety and all the operators I want.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to avoid empty classes in your case I can see is to do something like that:

```
interface INumeric<T>
{
    T Add(T num);
    T Substract(T num);
    T Multiply(T num);
    T Divide(T num);
}
class Quantity<T> where T : INumeric<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public static Quantity<T> operator + (Quantity<T> left, Quantity<T> right) 
    {
        return new Quantity<T>() { Value = left.Value.Add(right.Value) };
    }

    public static Quantity<T> operator - (Quantity<T> left, Quantity<T> right) 
    {
        return new Quantity<T>() { Value = left.Value.Substract(right.Value) };
    }

    public static Quantity<T> operator / (Quantity<T> left, Quantity<T> right)
    {
        return new Quantity<T>() { Value = left.Value.Divide(right.Value) };
    }

    public static Quantity<T> operator * (Quantity<T> left, Quantity<T> right)
    {
        return new Quantity<T>() { Value = left.Value.Multiply(right.Value) };
    }
}
```

Then you have to implement `INumeric<T>` in `Unit` and each unit can have it's own implementation of this methods

Comment: That can't work, because T can be of different Unit type, and you forgot to take the Unit parameter in the Quantity constructor.